# Finding all the elements of a specific group with a given order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is an exercise from the abstract algebra textbook from Dan Saracino. It asks me to find all the elements of $(Z_{45},\oplus)$ that have an order of $15$. As I understand it, the order of an element $x$ will be the smallest integer $n$ (aside from $0$) such that $x^n$ gives me the identity of the group. In this case, it would be all the numbers that divided by $45$ would give me remainder of $0$. With that in mind, I wrote the set of the numbers with order $15$ as follows:

$G = \{ x | 15x = 45k, k \in Z\}$

Knowing that $x \leq 45 $ I started punching numbers with the answers in hand. For $k = 1$ and $k = 2$ I got the right answers, $x = 3$ and $x =6$ respectively. But for $k = 3$, for example, $x = 9$ is not a correct answer, and so on with several $k$. I suspect this has something to do with the congruency of some of the numbers I get (that being, the answers that are not correct are congruent with some of the smaller numbers) but I'm not sure how to prove it.

If this is not the correct place to answer a "homework question", I apologize. I'm self-learning so I don't really have a teacher to ask.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $15x=45k$ is equivalent to $x=3k$, so every multiple of $3$ will have order dividing $15$. But $9$ and its multiples will have order dividing $5$, and $15$ and its multiples will have order dividing $3$, so what you want are the multiples of $3$, excluding both the multiples of $9$ and the multiples of $15$.

Comment: Could you expand on the "order dividing $n$"? I don't believe I have read that concept yet.

Comment: If $x$ is a multiple of $3$, say, $x=3k$, then $15x=45k\equiv0\bmod{45}$. But it is possible that some number $m$ smaller than $15$ will satisfy $mx\equiv0\bmod{45}$. Suppose in fact $m$ is the smallest positive number such that $mx\equiv0\bmod{45}$ (this makes $m$ the order of $x$ modulo $45$). We have $15=mq+r$ for some quotient $q$ and some remainder $r$, $0\le r<m$. Then $rx=(15-mq)x=15x-(mx)q\equiv0-0=0\bmod{45}$. So $r$ must be zero, and $m$ must divide $15$. Similarly for the other places where I wrote about an order dividing some number.

Comment: Just to confirm i'm understanding you correctly, $9$ and its multiples, and $15$ and its multiples have members that become the identity with $n$ less than $15$, so that makes the order of such of members not $15$. And thanks for the followup!

Comment: Yes, you do understand correctly.